# Can limit be taken inside a function which has a removable Discontinuity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I got this doubt while solving this problem:

Given $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$   $$g(x)=0$$

and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0, \quad & \text{ if } x \ne 0, \\
           1, &\text{ if } x = 0\end{cases}$$

Now we have $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0 \ne f(0)$$ hence $f$ has Removable Discontinuity at $x=0$

Also  $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=0$$

Its quite obvious that $f(g(x)=1$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Hence $$\lim_{x \to 0} f\left(g(x)\right)=1$$

But $$f\left(\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\right)=f(0)=1$$

So can Limit and function be interchanged when the function has Removable discontinuity?

Comment: What happens for $g(x)=x$?

Answer (score 1):

No, in your example magically values are equal , so it does not mean you can take the limit inside.

Consider

$$g(x)=x^2$$

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x+1, \quad & \text{ if } x \ne 1, \\
           4, &\text{ if } x = 1\end{cases}$$

we have $$f\left(g(x)\right)= \begin{cases} x^2+1, \quad & \text{ if } x \ne \pm1, \\
           4, &\text{ if } x = \pm1\end{cases}$$

So $$\lim_{x \to 1}f(g(x))=2$$  while

$$f\left(\lim_{x \to 1} g(x)\right)=4$$